# java.io.IOException when getting data from error response

Tags: java, kotlin, fuel

I have implemented a simple **POST** request for login API.

```
val fuelRequest = Fuel.post(urlString)
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .header("Accept", "application/json")
    .jsonBody(UtilsString.getStringForDictionary(params))

fuelRequest.response() { _, response, result ->
    ...
    callback.onComplete(result)
}
```

When the response is ok, there is no problem. The problem occurs when I try to get the data response from an error request. The data that I get is this :

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "error": "The specified credentials are invalid."
}
```

And this comes with a 401 Unauthorised response. I've just wanted to get the message from de request. If I try `response.data` it throws **Method threw 'java.io.IOException** If I try `result.component()2.response` it throws **Method threw 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Response.toString()** If I try `result.error.errorData` it throws Method threw 'java.io.IOException

Any clue how can I get the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't add code snippet in the comment but here is the code snippet. You could take the request something like this and do whatever you want according to your usecase.

```
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.Fuel
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.FuelError
import com.github.kittinunf.result.Result

private class ResponseError(
        val statusCode: Int,
        val statusMessage: String,
        val errorMessage: String
) : RuntimeException("[%d - %s] %s".format(statusCode, statusMessage, errorMessage))

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val (request, response, result) = Fuel.post("http://httpbin.org/post").responseString()

    when (result) {
        is Result.Failure -> onError(result)
    }
    print("done")
}

/**
 *
 */
fun onError(failureResult: Result.Failure<String, FuelError>) {
    throw ResponseError(
            statusCode = failureResult.error.response.statusCode,
            statusMessage = failureResult.error.response.responseMessage,
            errorMessage = failureResult.getErrorMessage())
}

/**
 *
 */
private fun Result.Failure<String, FuelError>.getErrorMessage(): String {
    return try {
        val string = String(this.error.errorData)
        print(string)
        string
    } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
        ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code and if I add this:

```
findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener { view ->
            val fuelRequest = Fuel.post("http://10.0.2.2:3000/")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .jsonBody(UtilsString.getStringForDictionary(params))

            fuelRequest.response() { _, response, _ ->
                println(String(response.data))
            }
}
```

I can see the body of the error response.
The endpoint 10.0.2.2:3000 is a small express.js application which delivers just a small json.

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.status(401).jsonp({ error: 'failed' })
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me check

Answer (score 0):

You could get the response like this and do whatever you want with the response.

```
Fuel.post("https://api.chui.ai/v1/enroll")
                            .header(headers)
                            .body(json.toString(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
                            .responseString(new com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Handler<String>() {

                            @Override
                            public void failure(@NotNull com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Request request,
                                                @NotNull com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Response response,
                                                @NotNull FuelError error) {
                                Log.d("Fuel.failure", error.getMessage());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void success(@NotNull com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Request request,
                                                @NotNull com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Response response,
                                                String data) {
                                // data is a string, parse as using you fav json library
                                Log.d("Fuel.success", data);
                            }
```